# Serving static files via Express - endpoint specific?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Beginner here, please point me in the right direction! So, I used express static and can see all my static files correctly in "sources" and the CSS applies via localhost:5050. However, when I directly open my endpoint e.g. http://localhost:5500/users, I cannot see the files anymore and no more CSS is applied. I wrote requests for each specific endpoint too, of course. Does this have anything to do with the way I serve static files in my code? I can't for the life of me figure out why there are no errors in the console and network tab but the styles do not apply and the classes set in my script also do not show up via the elements page in the dev tools when I open any of my endpoints. What could be the problem if everything is working via index? Do I need to configure static files for each API endpoint somehow too?

- note: I also console.logged the path and could see the path is correct - / also serves the static files correctly so I assume the issue lies somewhere else? I also tried `app.use('/users',express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'public')));`
  and could then see all static files via that endpoint but the whole endpoint functionality I set later in the code broke & `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'public')));` should normally allow public folder access from all endpoints, right?

**HTML tags:**

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" type="text/css">
  <script src="./js/bundle.js"></script>
```

--> also tried with js/bundle.js & other paths.

**server.js:**

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import axios from 'axios';
      
    const __dirname = path.dirname(new URL(import.meta.url).pathname);
    
    const app = express();
    const port = 5500;
    
    // Serve static files from the public folder
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'public')));
    
    // Route for serving the index.html file
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'public', 'index.html'));
    });
    
    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
    });
```

**This is my folder structure:**

```
 public/
    index.html
    css/
      style.css
    js/
      bundle.js
  src/
    client/
      script.js
    server/
      proxy.js
      server.js
```

Comment: I don't see `app.get('/users'...)` anywhere. What is `/users` endpoint?

Comment: @Konrad /users is an example but I did create other endpoints for my specific API and they work as they should. I just cannot see the static files via other endpoints, as I can see via index (e.g. my js and css folders). Is that supposed to be this way? And if so, why is the CSS not applied on other endpoints?     I thought app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'public'))); is supposed to give me access to all static files in public from any endpoints.

Comment: Most likely the paths in the html files are wrong

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thanks both. I tried to change the paths to all kinds of variants already without luck. I just edited to include my folder structure.

Comment: If you want to render `index.html` on any path (not only on root `/`). You should use `app.use((req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'public', 'index.html'));` instead of `app.get('/', ...)`. P.s. and you should also fix script src path to make it absolute `/js/bundle.js` as LawrenceCherone noted.

Answer (score 0):

When you use code like this:

```js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'public')));
```

Means that every request goes through `express.static` middleware.
Static middleware get path from the URL and tries to match a static file in `public` directory to this path. Let's consider several examples:

- `GET https://localhost:5500/foo/bar.html` -> would be converted to `/public/foo/bar.html`
- `GET https://localhost:5500/` -> `public/index.html`
- `GET https://localhost:5500/users/` -> `public/users/index.html`

If you replace `app.use(express.static(...))` on `app.use('/users', express.static(...))` then express.static would be called only on `/users/...` requests:

- `GET https://localhost:5500/foo/bar.html` -> not called
- `GET https://localhost:5500/users/` -> `public/index.html`. Note, `/users` prefix is removed when express.static convert URL's path to file path.

So this should explain:

> I also tried app.use('/users',express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'public'))); and could then see all static files via that endpoint

Goes next:

```js
   app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'public', 'index.html'));
    });
```

applies only on `/` request, so if you make request on `/users` express returns 404. If you want fallback on `index.html` every request that didn't match any previous middleware you should use:

```js
   app.use((req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'public', 'index.html'));
    });
```

And the last `./js/bundle.js`:

```html
<script src="./js/bundle.js"></script>
```

this is relative URL it means if you open page `/users/index.html` and render such HTML then browser will make request on `/users/js/bundle.js`. In you case I guess you want to make request always on `/js/bundle.js` so you should replace it on absolute path `/js/bundle.js` like you did for CSS

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply! :) That clarifies a part of my question. But, I still cannot see any other static files when I open other endpoints in the browser, only my index "/". This line: app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'public'))); is supposed to match any endpoints to static files in the public folder but I can't see them via "sources" & my CSS is not applied on the other endpoints still. I changed the paths already without luck (edited my question already). Do you know why this?

Comment: (And yes, the endpoints exist with their respective app.get functions & show the JS I applied in bundle.js correctly).

Comment: So e.g. http://localhost:5500/users/media - shows all the images I accessed from the API but no CSS is applied and sources in devTools do not show any other static files other than the index - while http://localhost:5500/ shows all static files & css is applied.

Comment: How source html looks like on `/users/media`? You can check it via devtools or by `Show page source`

Comment: Yes, I know that or do you mean you want to know? It shows a user folder with the media and the index..no other statics. CSS also not applied. So my question is still unresolved sadly

Comment: @CuriousDevie I meant does HTML which you send on `/users/media` contains static files which you want to see in the browser? Maybe html which you render just doesn't have css ;)

Comment: No it does not. I assumed possibility that I need to see the static files in the browser, in order for them to apply on the other endpoints (here js & css static files are not showing)- since there is no explanation I get why css would only apply on the "/" otherwise. My CSS is also in the public folder and my index.html is also in the public folder. I tried changing CSS & the changes apply on index but not on other endpoints. Using *only1* stylesheet with link tag in HTML. Super confused as to what is happening here

Comment: All my logic is in index.html or bundle.js so questions are 1) why can I still not see my static files in my endpoints when the paths are correct & express static applied 2) do I need to see them for them to apply 3) how to apply css to other endpoints when just working with 1 JS + 1 HTML file otherwise & should they not apply to all endpoints automatically since they are extensions of "/"

Comment: @CuriousDevie I think you are getting wrong `& express static applied`. When you send request to `/users/media` express.static middleware try to find `public/users/media/index.html` but doesn't find it so it just call `next()` function which goes to you `express.get('/users/media',...)` handler which send as response to the browser. And you see in the browser what you send via `express.get('/users/media`,...)`.

Comment: If you send `res.send('Hello World!')` you will see just text in the browser. If you send you `/public/index.html` you will see what is inside that `index.html`. So what you send in `/users/media`?